# Check phone number has been used or not

Tags: php, android, mysql

First, user wanted to register to an app. Phone number is needed. Sometime we input phone number like this +9912345678 or this 012345678.

Then submit button will check the number phone has been used or not.

+9912345678 and 012345678 will be different phone number that they actually are same number. This is the problem...

The app only allow one username and one phone number are used once.

Login to app can use username or phone number with password.

this app using php and mysql as database.

What should I do ? Only coding with php or combine of php and mysql.
If using mysql, what's data type used for phone number ?
Thanks

Comment: Why not convert the number to an accepted format then do a simple `SELECT` on that table to see if the phone number is in use? Having the user input the number however they please is going to be a nightmare for you on the back-end.

Comment: `num_rows` or `count()` via MySQL

Comment: @Fred-ii- Why that? Why not a simple `INSERT` into a table with a unique index? If the insert succeeds: fine, if not, the row apparently already exists...

Comment: @arkascha I thought the OP wanted to check if one was taken. However, yours is a good solution. They have options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM t1
WHERE RIGHT(phone, 8) = RIGHT('064123456', 8)
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcc54/5) to see how it's work. And when execute that in php check if you have returned row or not if you have row in result than your number is in database...

**EDIT**
P.S. i put some random number for example... And I don't know which data type you use to store phone number this work if you use varchar... Also there is solution to before you enter number into database to format phone number

GL!